# Reasons for antiperiplanar arrangement in E2 reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry

From what I have learnt, there are 2 reasons that synperiplanar arrangement cannot give E2 reactions:

1. In Newman projection, synperiplanar arrangements is in a eclipsed form (very high in energy), so less likely to be in syn formation than anti. However, I am thinking that as the C-C sigma bond is always rotating, there is still a little chance for synperiplanar to undergo E2
2. In synperiplanar arrangement, the base (usually rich in electron density) will face a high electron repulsion with the leaving group when approaching the beta-hydrogen, hence reduce chance of successful E2.

However, these reasons only **reduce the chance** of synperiplanar arrangement from going E2, but cannot comepletely eliminating it. So I want to ask whether there are other reasons (e.g. cannot form / break the bonds if in synperiplanar during E2), in line with the experimental results that only anti can gives E2?

Comment: I'm fairly sure synperiplanar E2 reactions can happen; they're just less favourable. There is a classic case with norbornyl bromide where the ring system forces a syn elimination https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01067a018